# KEY_WOW64_32KEY not redirecting from x64 application

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I have an x64 application running on a x64 OS where i'm trying to read from the x86 registry.
This is my code:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Idontexist", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey);
```

I want to try to open **HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Idontexist**, but instead it's opening **HKCU\Software\Idontexist**.

I watched in process monitor and if I use KEY_WOW64_64KEY or KEY_WOW64_32KEY, both try to read **HKCU\Software\Idontexist**, instead of **HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Idontexist**.

EDIT: OS is Windows 7 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What keys are redirected and reflected on Windows 7 is shown in detail in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Too large to reproduce here, but you can clearly see that the HKCU\Software key, other than the Classes subkey, is *shared*, not redirected.

Answer (score 0):

`Wow6432Node` implies WOW64 virtualization.  A 64-bit process can open a 32-bit virtualized key directly:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Idontexist", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
```

If you need the same code to run in both 32-bit and 64-bit and both access the `Wow6432Node` key, then use `IsWow64Process()` in the 32-bit code to detect WOW64 and then adust the code accordingly, eg:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Idontexist", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
#else
BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64);
DWORD Wow64Flags = (bIsWow64) ? KEY_WOW64_32KEY : 0;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Idontexist", 0, KEY_READ | Wow64Flags, &hKey);
#endif
```

However, you really shouldn't be accessing `Wow6432Node` directly.  `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` should be working correctly if the target key is properly separated into 32-bit and 64-bit views:

```
DWORD Wow64Flags;
#ifdef _WIN64
Wow64Flags = KEY_WOW64_32KEY;
#else
BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64);
Wow64Flags = (bIsWow64) ? KEY_WOW64_32KEY : 0;
#endif
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Idontexist", 0, KEY_READ | Wow64Flags, &hKey);
```

If that is not working, than that implies that `Software\\Wow6432Node\\Idontexist` should not have existed in the first place, and was probably incorrectly created by a 64-bit process that did not use `KEY_WOW64_...` flags correctly.